# How to delete opposite pairs of rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of transactions and there are rows with negative sum_value and sum_units and their corresponding rows with the reverse (positive) sum_value and sum_units. I want to delete all these pairs.

Here is an example of a pair as described above:

```
payer_id    order_nubber  sum_units sum_value id_3rd_level  order_date               isCorporate   payment    tk
2003931     30010577        1       54.15       101011      2013-10-25 00:00:00.000        0         Cash   12244   
2003931     1200223605     -1      -54.15       101011      2013-10-25 00:00:00.000        0         Cash   12244
```

I tried this but it is not correct.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM transactions
    WHERE sum_value < 0
)
DELETE tr
FROM transactions tr
INNER JOIN CTE
ON CTE.payer_id = tr.payer_id
WHERE CTE.sum_value = (-1) * tr.sum_value AND CTE.sum_units = (-1) * tr.sum_units AND 
CTE.order_date = tr.order_date AND CTE.isCorporate = tr.isCorporate AND
CTE.tk = tr.tk
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You want **both** rows gone or just one of them?

Comment: What if a payer has multiple rows that are opposites? For example, 55, 55, and -55. Also, I hope that this is for data clean-up of some kind of a data problem, because deleting transaction records in an accounting system would be a REALLY bad idea.

Comment: @Jan I want to delete both rows.

Comment: @TomH This is for an excercise, I have to clean up the dataset. I have already delete rows that are duplicated, so in your example the one row with the value 55 is already deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finds all rows with the same absolute `sum_value` and `sum_units` (which might be more than two):

```
--DELETE tr
SELECT *
FROM transactions AS tr
WHERE EXISTS
 ( SELECT * FROM transactions AS tr2
   WHERE tr.payer_id    = tr2.payer_id
     AND tr.sum_value   = -tr2.sum_value 
     AND tr.sum_units   = -tr2.sum_units
     AND tr.order_date  = tr2.order_date 
     AND tr.isCorporate = tr2.isCorporate 
     AND tr.tk          = t2.tk
 )
```

Of course you should double check before by actually delete.